# How do I use routing in an angular app with Ionic tabs?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I have been trying to add routes to my Ionic app with tabs, but to no avail. Whenever I add any routes to my routes array and update the app, the localhost server returns a blank screen. I also get this error in the Developer Tools console:

> Comonent MessagesComponent is not a part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Here is my app-routing module file:

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1/tab1.page';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs/tabs.page';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent},
  //This is how you define routes for tabs  
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot( routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You need to get a little bit more familiar with Angular. The error tells you what to do. You need to import the message component into your module's declarations section. So I assume you have some `app.module.ts` somewhere when you already have `AppRoutingModule`. Add this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';  // <------

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessagesComponent, // <------
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In general I would recommend you to outsource the message component into a message module and lazy load it like you did with `TabsPageModule` and the `tab1` lazy technic is old.

**Now back to tabs**

That is how it would look like:

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

const defaultRout = "/tabs"

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then((m) => m.TabsModule),
  },

  // 404
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: defaultRout, // or 404 module
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

#### tab-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

import { TabsComponent } from './tabs.component'

const defaultRoute = "/tabs"

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // tabs
    component: TabsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: defaultRoute,
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },

      // Routes
      {
        path: 'explore',
        loadChildren: () => import('../explore/explore.module').then((m) => m.ExploreModule),
      },

      // 404
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: defaultRoute,
      },
    ],
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsRoutingModule {}
```

You see here that everything is in its own folder and has its own module. This prevents some issues later and also makes everything more modular.

PS: you can add syntax highlighting in SO: ```` ```typescript ````

Comment: Hi. I created the messages module and then outsourced the messages component to it. Then I created a route to that module. Now it displays the app when I serve it to the browser. The problem is when I try to navigate to the messages component using a link I generated, I don't get any response. I've inspected my routes using augury and found that the messages component is indeed routed to. What may be the problem? Also, thanks for the syntax highlighting tip.

Comment: Have a look where you set the `path` name. Inside a modules routing module should be an entry point without any route name (see in my code above), which gets a default route. It may also be that you forgot to add the component to the module you are routing to. So messages component must be in message module and not AppModule.

Comment: Hi. I've tried everything and still cant find the problem. The app renders but still doesn't route. Perhaps you could help me find the issue by looking at the project on github... https://github.com/agingaRichard/zapmessenger

Comment: I have made a working PR: https://github.com/agingaRichard/zapmessenger/pull/1